# Plotting pixel by pixel with R

Tags: r, ggplot2

For some unfortunate technical reasons, I need to have a pixel plot. 
For example, let's take this simple plot:

```
plot(0,0)
Points(x=1:10, y=rep(0,10), cex=1)
```

I need each dot to be *exactly* a pixel wide. The size parameter cex does not seem to allow such precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ggplot` with the option `geom_point(shape = ".")`.

For example

```
# generate random dataframe
df <- data.frame(x = runif(100), y = runif(100)) 

# make the figure
ggplot(df) + aes(x = x, y = y) + geom_point(shape = ".") + theme_void()
```

This will create something like:

[image]